# Nginx will not serve static files

Tags: python, django, nginx, server, gunicorn

I have been at this for hours trying to figure out how to serve the static files using nginx and nothing will work. I'm using Django and gunicorn as well. 
My config:

```
server {
     listen 80;
     server_name mysitename;

     location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
     }

      location /static {
         autoindex on;
         alias /home/cmc/sites/mysitename/;
     }

}
```

my settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../static')
```

When I run gunicorn:

```
[2015-04-11 01:17:50 +0000] [12354] [INFO] Starting unicorn 19.3.0

[2015-04-11 01:17:50 +0000] [12354] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (12354)

[2015-04-11 01:17:50 +0000] [12354] [INFO] Using worker: sync

[2015-04-11 01:17:50 +0000] [12357] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12357
```

EDIT: It's not working because it's not loading the CSS on the page.

Comment: How is it not working? Is nginx giving you a 403 error? 404? 500? What does nginx's error log say?

Comment: What is in `/home/cmc/sites/mysitename/`? If there’s a `static` directory, use `root`, not `alias`.

Comment: @Blender I edited the original post to explain why. The page runs but the CSS does not display. error log: 2015/04/11 01:34:11 [error] 12353#0: *215 open() "/home/cmc/sites/mysitename//base.css" failed (13: Permission denied)

Comment: Which user is Nginx running as? Try `user cmc;`.

Comment: @minitech cmc is running it with sudo privileges but I also have access to root. Maybe I should try running it from root? I'm a bit new to this stuff.

Comment: @drakoen: The Nginx process drops its root (usually) privileges (usually) to a user and group determined by the `user` and `group` options. They are probably at the very top of your `nginx.conf`.

Comment: @minitech That fixed it! Thank you. It had the user set as nginx. I changed it to cmc and it worked.